# jaxb unmarshall localDateTime multi thread environment

Tags: jaxb

In advance sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem when unmarshalling a string into a LocalDateTime in a multi thread environment. I generated the java classe (ActivityData) with org.apache.cxf version 2.7.7

When I debug the application from time to time the year of the string has been corrupted with some strange value at the beginning of the year (for instance 722008-01-01, A2008-01-01, 12008-01-01) when I make the call with a client like soap ui the date is well formatted. The localDateAdapter is called by multiple thread in a batch application. When I rerun the batch, the same call successes and others fails the parsing error is unpreddictable. The problem only occurs for the begin date the end date in the java object is always well formatted

I tried to synchronize the method but it doesn't change a thing.

Thanks in advance for your help

Here is the code of my LocalDateTimeAdapter

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
    public synchronized LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(v)) {
            try {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(v, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parsing problem in the localDateTime for string : " + v);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) {
        if (v != null) {
            return v.toString();
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

The generated class :

the binding file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_1.xsd"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
        version="2.1">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
        <xjc:javaType
                name="java.time.LocalDate"
                xmlType="xs:date"
                adapter="be.fgov.minfin.vies.adapter.LocalDateAdapter"/>
        <xjc:javaType
                name="java.time.LocalDateTime"
                xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                adapter="be.fgov.minfin.vies.adapter.LocalDateTimeAdapter"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

the generated class :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ActivityData", propOrder = {
    "beginDate",
    "endDate"
})
public class ActivityData
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected LocalDateTime beginDate;

    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected LocalDateTime endDate;


    /**
     * Gets the value of the beginDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public LocalDateTime getBeginDate() {
        return beginDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the beginDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setBeginDate(LocalDateTime value) {
        this.beginDate = value;
    }


    /**
     * Gets the value of the endDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public LocalDateTime getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the endDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEndDate(LocalDateTime value) {
        this.endDate = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow this is suspicious. I can recognize thread safety problems in your code. `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` created from pattern are immutable and thread-safe. You should try to provide a reproducing MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the string "v" is already corrupted when entering in the unmarshall method . Mark the method as synchronized isnt enough to handle thread issues ?

Comment: If you know you have corrupted data on input, why even ask? The problem is obviously not in the adapter then.

Comment: *Mark the method as synchronized isnt enough to handle thread issues ?* - In this case I can't recognize thread safety issues with your code. I don't even see why you'd need `synchronized` here.

Comment: Thank you. This is why I m looking for help. I dont get why I m receiving this corrupted string. It has something to do with the parsing of the XML To the java object... I cant figure it out

Comment: First of all, build a reproducing test case (MCVE).

Comment: It is unlikely that the problem is in date parsing or JAXB.